# htaccess on passing 1 query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess path is something such as

```
/home/user1/public_html/subdomain/user/transfer/.htaccess
```

I have a index.php on the same folder as the .htaccess

the index.php is trying to capture the query string "action" by rewrite action as the last query which something like

```
subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/action
```

where action could be cash , credit, loan or other words , to Alexander and @Trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you get a request

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=register
```

and want to treat is internally as

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/transferregister
```

then you should place in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^transfer/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* transfer/transfer%1? [R=302,L]
```

If you want the opposite, that is, you get a request

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/transferregister
```

and want to treat is internally as

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=register
```

then you should place in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^transfer/transfer
RewriteRule ^transfer/transfer(.*)$ transfer/index.php?action=$1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I tried your htaccess but it give me an error The requested URL /user/transfer/transfer1 was not found on this server.

Comment: but this is exactly what you want? Just check whether you have a directory transfer1.

Or do you want the opposite? What is your input and what do you want to redirect it to?

Comment: I think opposite, i get a request of http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/transferregister and want to load the content of http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=register but the url is http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/transferregister

Comment: Does it work for you now? If yes, please accept the answer :-)

Comment: @Alexander: I think you mean to have your `RewriteCond` line as `^transfer/transfer.*$`.  Otherwise, I believe it will only match `/user/transfer/transfer`.

Comment: @Trick No, we do need `()` here, otherwise `$1` will not work! Why do you believe it will only match `/user/transfer/transfer`? Did you check?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh: Yes, you need the () on the `RewriteRule` line, but you are trying to match ^transfer/transfer$ for your `RewriteCond`, which wouldn't match _transfer/transfer1_.  It should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} transfer/transfer.*$`.  This works for me, whereas the `^transfer/transfer$` did not.

Comment: @Trick: OOPS, I looked at `RewriteRule` line. Sorry. You are right: in `RewriteCond` it should be `^transfer/transfer`, I just copied it from above and forgot to remove the `$`. Changing the answer.

Comment: Hi Alexander and @Trick if I want to match transfer/*, is it just ^transfer where * is a word , perhaps cash, credit or loan

Comment: @user3504335: to match a wildcard, the proper regex would be `^transfer/.*`, but I believe `^transfer` will work as well.

Comment: @user3504335: `^transfer/` is the same as `^transfer/.*$` and `transfer/` is the same as `.*transfer/.*`, which also matches `sometransfer/` and `transfer/index.html`. Probably you need `^transfer/`.

Comment: @Trick and Alexander, I tried the changes , I updated my new .htaccess at my question, but it seem cannot find too.

Comment: @user3504335, please post the updated contents of your _.htaccess_.

Comment: @user3504335: you can try removing `Rewrite Base /user/` and using `^user/transfer/transfer` instead of `transfer/transfer` in both patterns.

Comment: @Trick, I posted it, at my question, and also updated the url I access using index.php

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh , my pattern does not involve 2 transfer, there only 1 transfer, the url I trying access is ^user/transfer/cash , or ^user/transfer/credit or cash/credit could be other word too

Comment: @user3504335, try the following:  

    #prevent a redirect loop
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} transfer/index.php  
    RewriteRule ^ transfer/index.php [L]  
`
    
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} transfer/.*  
    RewriteRule ^transfer/(.*)$ transfer/index.php?action=$1 [R=302,L]  
`

Alternatively, you could use:

    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} transfer/(cash|credit)$  
    RewriteRule ^transfer/(.*)$ transfer/index.php?action=$1 [R=302,L]  `

Comment: @user3504335: where do you place your `.htaccess`? If in /user, then you probably should remove `RewriteBase /user/`. If in /user/transfer, then you should also remove `RewriteCond` and leave only `RewriteRule (.*)` because you are already in transfer/.: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1? [R=302,L]` in the latter case.

Comment: I tried both condition, I still get the same error of not found

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh , the .htaccess is in user/transfer folder

Comment: @user3504335: try `
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1? [R=302,L]
` without `RewriteBase`.

Comment: If i try RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1? [R=302,L] , I get this /home/user1/public_html/account/user/transfer/index.php was not found on this server.  , if i add in the RewriteCond  !^index\.php , i get a 500 error

Comment: @user3504335: try `
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?action=$1 [R=302,L]
` without `RewriteBase`.

Comment: @user3504335: ` /home/user1/public_html/account/user/transfer/index.php` was not what you wanted? Then maybe check the `RewriteBase` again. Then your configuration is not what I expected. Maybe then try `RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=$1 [R]` as a last resort.

Comment: Issue is resolve, got it solve at another spot, the solution was with 
RewriteBase /user/transfer/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]